# Fetch List of Items from Quote

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

We are using "softlayer api client" in our java application. we are trying to fetch complete quote details(Quote Information & items/Products Details which are part of the quote). We found method to fetch quote information. However, We don't find method which gives items/products which are part of quote. Is there any method to get the List of items that are available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this methods:

https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Order_Quote/getOrder
https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Order_Quote/getRecalculatedOrderContainer

e.g RESTFul

```
GET https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Billing_Order_Quote/$QUOTEID/getOrder
```